# getting PDP-11 DL11 output via telnet

Tags: assembly, pdp-11, simh

I'm trying to run the (a slightly adapted version but the original gives the same problem) example program from [How to implement a 'write' function in pdp-11 / MACRO-11 / ODT using simh?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15486/how-to-implement-a-write-function-in-pdp-11-macro-11-odt-using-simh) in simh.
I would like to see its output in a file or a telnet session.

For that I assembled it using https://github.com/pdpy11/pdpy11 Then I added a header and loaded it in simh:

```
sim> set dli en
sim> set dlo en
sim> attach dli 2222
Listening on port 2222 (socket 3)
sim> load test2.bin
sim> run
```

The program then runs upto the trap statement that I added after the jsr.

Unfortunately, I receive no output on telnet port 2222.

```
start:  MOV #stack_end, R6
    MOV #text, R0
    CALL    printstart
    TRAP    07

text:   .ASCII  "test\x00"

printstart: MOV R0,-(SP)

print:  CMPB    #00,(R0)
    BEQ pdone

    MOVB    (R0), @#TTYTX

waittx: TSTB    @#TTYST
    BPL waittx

    INC R0
    JMP print

pdone:  MOV (SP)+,R0
    RET

    make_raw

stack:  .BLKB   4096.
stack_end:

TTYST   =   177564
TTYTX   =   177566
```

What should I do in simh to make this work?

Thanks.

p.s. pdpy11 assembler does not add a .bin-header, for that I wrote https://vanheusden.com/emulation/pdp11/raw_to_simh_bin.tgz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

177564 is the CSR address of the console tty output.

Your simh configuration is adding an actual DL11 device, which will have a different address.  The output CSR for the first DL11 is 176504; this is confirmed by the peripherals handbook as quoted in [my answer here](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/23940/trap-stack-push-abort-on-the-pdp-11-with-simh/23943#23943), and by simh itself:

```
sim> sho tto
TTO     address=17777564-17777567, vector=64, BR4, 7p
sim> show dli
DLI     address=17776500-17776677, vector=300-474*, BR4, lines=16
sim> show dlo
DLO     16 units
  DLO0  UC, no dataset, no logging
   :
```

If you just want to test your program, I suggest attaching to the console tty.  Alternatively, try the DL11 unit 0 address.

Comment: So I do "r" / "set console telnet=3333" / "load test.bin" / "run"? Because the only output I get the on telnet port 3333 is "Connected to the PDP-11 simulator". I also added cr/lf to my test-output but that did not help (in case it is lined-based).

Comment: Oh never mind: it does work with the original example when I move the string behind the code so that it doesn't get executed :-)